# iOS Swift coordinates function returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, geocoding

I'm working on a function to convert a city (string) to coordinates. However, when I call the function I get "(0.0, 0.0)" as a result. It should be the latitude and longitude.

Please help me out. Thanks!

This is the function

```
func getCoordinates(huidigeLocatie: String) -> (lat: CLLocationDegrees, long: CLLocationDegrees) {

    var lat:CLLocationDegrees
    var long:CLLocationDegrees

    var geocoderHuidigeLocatie = CLGeocoder()

    geocoderHuidigeLocatie.geocodeAddressString(huidigeLocatie, completionHandler:
        {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

            if error != nil {

                println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            } else if placemarks.count > 0 {

                let placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
                let location = placemark.location

                var lat = location.coordinate.latitude
                var long = location.coordinate.longitude

            }
    })

    return (lat: CLLocationDegrees(), long: CLLocationDegrees())
}
```

Comment: I guess that if your log the `lat` & `long` in the `else if` test, it's working? Then, your issue could be because it's asynchronous (as specified in the doc).

Comment: I've been debugging it and it turns out it doesn't even run the if statement. I don't know why that is.

Leonardo, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. You want to return the actual `lat` and `long` variables, not `CLLocationDegrees()`.
2. A more subtle issue is that you're calling a function that returns its results asynchronously, so you cannot return the values immediately. Instead, you might employ your own completionHandler pattern.

For example:

```
func getCoordinates(huidigeLocatie: String, completionHandler: (lat: CLLocationDegrees!, long: CLLocationDegrees!, error: NSError?) -> ()) -> Void {

    var lat:CLLocationDegrees
    var long:CLLocationDegrees

    var geocoderHuidigeLocatie = CLGeocoder()

    geocoderHuidigeLocatie.geocodeAddressString(huidigeLocatie) { (placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in

        if error != nil {

            println("Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

            completionHandler(lat: nil, long: nil, error: error)

        } else if placemarks.count > 0 {

            let placemark = placemarks[0] as CLPlacemark
            let location = placemark.location

            let lat = location.coordinate.latitude
            let long = location.coordinate.longitude

            completionHandler(lat: lat, long: long, error: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And you'd call it like so:

```
getCoordinates(string) { lat, long, error in
    if error != nil { 
        // handle the error here 
    } else {
        // use lat, long here
    }
}

// but not here
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `return (lat: lat, long: long)`.

Comment: Yes, this solves the "return the right variables" problem. But there's a deeper problem that he's trying to immediately return data that will only be obtained asynchronously. Instead, the OP should employ completion handler closure pattern.

Comment: @Rob Just googled to check and "completion handler closure pattern" isn't standard terminology... Do you mean putting the return statement within the block?

Comment: No, I do not mean that. Look at the `CLGeocoder` method `geocodeAddressString`. It has a `completionHandler` parameter which is called asynchronously (i.e. the function returns immediately, but the block/closure with the geocode data is called later when the address lookup is done). you should employ the same pattern in your own code.